# How to take the date of the last saturday for every next year of a given startdate

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to take the date of the last saturday from a given startdate.
for example :

> > Startdate = #9/28/2013#

then I want to take the last saturday for every next year from that startdate, it would be:

> > The saturday in 2014 is : 27 sept 2014

it will always be updated on every year, the next again is:

> > The saturday in 2015 is : 26 sept 2015

and next again is :

> The saturday in 2016 is : 24 sept 2016

it run like the usual date but the start is not 1/1/[year] but [the date on saturday]/9/year...
I will accept the logic both in vb or c#...
here is my code in vb.net:

> > Dim DstartDate As Date
>
> DstartDate = #9/28/2013#

```
tnextyear = DstartDate.AddYears(1)
    tyear = tnextyear.Year
    tmonth = tnextyear.Month
    tdate = tnextyear.Day
    tday = tnextyear.DayOfWeek.ToString()
    Dim ttdate As Date
     If (tday <> "Saturday") Then
        ttdate = tnextyear.AddDays(-1)
        tday = ttdate.DayOfWeek.ToString()
        If tday <> "Saturday" Then
            ttdate = tnextyear.AddDays(-2)
            tday = ttdate.DayOfWeek.ToString()
        End If       
    End If
    tday = ttdate.DayOfWeek.ToString()
    tyear += 1
    lbltestYear.Text = tday & tyear
```

it doesn't execute the if condidition.... the label display the tday before "if"... in that code I put the condition to substract the date if it is not "Saturday", because every year the date will decreased one to get saturday and on every 4 years decreased 2... I didn't put the condition for every 4 years yet because I just to see how the output of that code...

Thanks in advance... and sorry about before,,,,

Comment: "I will accept the solution both in vb or c#" - We will, too. Show us your effort in either.

Comment: oops... sorry I forget to add my code.... I will edit it...

Comment: Most Date libraries should handle this for you.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I am sorry,, I really forget to put the code... I already edit it... Thanks for reminding me...

Comment: @rots so sorry,,, I already edit it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you need to get dates for next 10 years

```
Dim Startdate As DateTime = #9/28/2013# 

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
   Dim d As DateTime = Startdate.AddYears(i)
   Console.WriteLine(d.AddDays(-(d.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday) - 1))
Next
```

This code is valid for en-US culture (week starts from Sunday)

P.S.

The above code returns last Saturday for the same day for every year. If you need to get the last Saturday *of the month* then use

```
Dim Startdate As DateTime = #9/28/2013# 

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
   Dim d As DateTime = New DateTime(Startdate.Year + i, Startdate.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1)
   Do While d.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday
       d = d.AddDays(-1)
   Loop
   Console.WriteLine(d)
Next
```

Comment: Did you check what happens when i = 4?  It's impossible for the last Saturday to fall on the 23rd of September.

Comment: @Garry Vassood Good point. I thought the question was related to the given start date and month. Updated.

Comment: Your new code looks much better, do you have an attribution for its source?

Comment: @smirnov Thanks for helping me... I already get the solution. Unfortunately the logic I used on the post above was wrong that's why I change it. I just used +52 for the week to get saturday for next year. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# solution...

```
    public static void FindLastSaturday(int month, int startYear, int numberOfYears)
    {
        var dates = Enumerable.Range(startYear, numberOfYears)
            .Select(q => FilterFunc(new DateTime(q, month, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(q, month))));
        foreach (DateTime lastSaturday in dates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastSaturday.ToString("R"));
        }
    }
    private static DateTime FilterFunc(DateTime arg)
    {
        if (arg.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            return arg;
        }
        return FilterFunc(arg.AddDays(-1));
    }
```

It uses LINQ to project a range of dates and coerce them into the last Saturday.  Output from a sample looks like this...

```
Sat, 27 Sep 2014 00:00:00 GMT
Sat, 26 Sep 2015 00:00:00 GMT
Sat, 24 Sep 2016 00:00:00 GMT
Sat, 30 Sep 2017 00:00:00 GMT
Sat, 29 Sep 2018 00:00:00 GMT
```

Note that the LINQ gives the correct answer for 2017, where Saturday falls on the last day of the month.

Comment: Dear Garry, Thanks for helping me. The problem has been solved.

Comment: @user3567963, no probs, since the code was essentially used by smirnov to correct his answer, I will add this one to the Community Wiki.